# How to create new column from sum of two column in datatable c#

Tags: c#, calculated-columns, datacolumn

I have a datatable (table) in which there are a column named Col1 and i want to create column Col2. 
I want to get value of Col2[cell"1"] from sum of Col2[cell "2"] and Col1[cell"3"]

[Like what is in this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sUQj.png)

I'm using this following code:

```
        DataColumn Col2 = new DataColumn();
        Col2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
        Col2.ColumnName = "Col2";
        table.Columns.Add(Col2);
        DataRow row;
        for(int i = 1; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            row = table.NewRow();
            row["Col2"] = row["Col2",(i-1)] + row["col1"]
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Comment: How are you getting the data into this table? If from DB, a lagged self-join will serve nicely.

Comment: In first place, thank you for your answer and yes i'm getting the data from DB. 
I apologize for not mentioning it in my topic.

Comment: Can you share the query itself? I can recommend changes to that for the functionality you need.

Comment: I think [this documentation on expression columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/creating-expression-columns) might be what you are looking for.